# Laravel : Add all values of a column belonging to a specific id

Tags: php, laravel, sum, pivot-table

To understand my problem here is my database.

Basically you can create a "session" with different "dates" , "school" , number of "places"... like this :

```
id | starting | endding | places | school_id | published |
```

In this session you can create multiples lesson with a "starting" hour and an "ending" hour, a specific teacher "contributor" , "subject" , "date" ect... like this :

```
id | date | starting | endding | room | subject_id | contributor_id | course_session_id | level_id |
```

In my views I calculate the number of hours of all courses with this function

```
@foreach ($courseSession->lessons as $key => $lesson)     
      <tbody>                 
        <tr>
        <td>  
            {{$lesson->date}}            
          </td>
          <td>                                
                {{$lesson->contributor->firstname}} {{$lesson->contributor->lastname}}
          </td>
          <td>          
            {{$lesson->subject->name}}          
          </td>
          <td>
          {{$lesson->level->name}}
          </td>          
          <td>
            {{$lesson->starting}} - {{$lesson->endding}}
          </td>
          <td>
          <?php
          $dateDeb= strtotime($lesson->starting);
          $dateFin=strtotime($lesson->endding);
          $heureTot= date('H:i',$dateFin-$dateDeb);
          ?>
          {{ $heureTot}} //It showing me how long the lessons is (like 2 hours)
          </td>       
   @endforeach
```

By the way this is my controller

```
public function pdfshow($id)
{
    $session = CourseSession::find($id); 
    $courseSession = CourseSession::where('id',$id)->first();
 
    return view('fichestagepdf',['session'=>$session],["contributors" => Contributor::all(),'courseSession'=>$courseSession, 'levels'=>Level::all()]);
}
```

Now what I want to do is calculate all the hours of all the lessons of each contributor.So "sum" all the lessons of each "contributor".

I'm blocked with how to select each contributor and not have duplicates with the @foreach.

I want to reuse my function like adding all "starting" and "ending" column of each contributor and "ending - starting" = "totalhours" like the function before.

[Lesson table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV6Rg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your function from blade to another class like action, and call it from the controller. Ideally, blade files shouldn't be responsable to perform such tasks.

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions;

class GetTotalContributions
{
    public static function handle($lessons, $id = null)
    {
        return $id ? self::getTotal($lessons, $id) : self::getTotals($lessons));

    }

    private static function getTotals($lessons)
    {
        $contributions = [];

        $lessonsWithContributions = [];

        foreach ($lessons as $l) {
            $l->contibution = array_key_exists($l->contributor_id, $contributions)
                ? $contributions[$l->contributor_id]
                : self::getTotal($lessons, $l->contributor_id);

            $contributions[$l->contributor_id] = $l->contibution;

            $lessonsWithContributions[] = $l;
        }

        return $lessonsWithContributions;
    }

    private static function getTotal($lessons, $id)
    {
        return $lessons->where('contributor_id', $id)->reduce(
            function  ($carry, $current) {
                return $carry + self::getContribution($current)
            }
        );
    }

    private static function getContribution($lesseon)
    {
        return date('H:i', strtotime($current->endding) - strtotime($current->starting));
    }
}
```

BTW, I didn't run the code. There might be some issues, but it should be good enough to give you an idea how you can solve the problem.